# Python Dash Callback Timeout on Server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, plotly-dash

I have written an application using the python dash package (v1.6.1). I have deployed it to an EC2 with the Amazon Linux 2 Deep Learning AMI. This application takes several minutes to run an optimization problem based on user inputs. After about 1 minute, the application produces an error which says, "Callback error updating *name_of_div.children*".

Here is a small code sample to reproduce the error.

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import State, Input, Output
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import time

app = dash.Dash(
    __name__, meta_tags=[{"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device-width"}]
)
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button(
        "Run",
        id="button1",
    ),
    dcc.Slider(
        id="slider1",
        min=0,
        max=10,
        step=1,
        value=0,
    ),
    dcc.Loading(
        id="Loading1",
        children=[
            html.Div(id="out1", children=[html.P("Nothing yet")]),
        ],
        type="default"
    )
])

@app.callback(Output('out1', 'children'),
              [Input('button1', 'n_clicks')],
              [State('slider1', 'value')])
def update_page(n_clicks, value):
    if n_clicks is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        time.sleep(65)
        out_string = "The output is " + str(value)
        return html.P(out_string)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8050)
```

Is there a configuration causing the problem? Could it be network related? I can't find any similar posts with solutions. My issue sounds similar to [this unsolved one](https://community.plot.ly/t/does-callbacks-have-timeout-if-so-how-to-manipulate-it/26652).

Thanks!